# brew install mysql Can't set root password

Tags: mysql, homebrew

I installed MySQL via brew, but instead of letting me *set* a root password after `mysql_secure_installation`, I get *prompted* for the root password instead.

```
% brew install mysql
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/mysql/manifests/8.0.27
Already downloaded: /Users/msd/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/c521714052ea597d404fc2862523de823536b9d9c0f4be0bcefc34b8e280a2cf--mysql-8.0.27.bottle_manifest.json
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/mysql/blobs/sha256:dfd1d6855666
Already downloaded: /Users/msd/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/9a51cb7727b7e2d85fd2a1e02469666dff8e9d816b4d96ac68568577f741dea2--mysql--8.0.27.arm64_monterey.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring mysql--8.0.27.arm64_monterey.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
We've installed your MySQL database without a root password. To secure it run:
    mysql_secure_installation

MySQL is configured to only allow connections from localhost by default

To connect run:
    mysql -uroot

To restart mysql after an upgrade:
  brew services restart mysql
Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:
  /opt/homebrew/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/opt/homebrew/var/mysql
==> Summary
  /opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/8.0.27: 304 files, 294MB
==> Running `brew cleanup mysql`...
Disable this behaviour by setting HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_CLEANUP.
Hide these hints with HOMEBREW_NO_ENV_HINTS (see `man brew`).

% mysql_secure_installation

Enter password for user root: 
Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I then try `% mysqld --skip-grant-tables` to reset the password, but get another error:

````
2021-12-05T18:28:46.319410Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/8.0.27/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.27) starting as process 3482
2021-12-05T18:28:46.320508Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /opt/homebrew/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
2021-12-05T18:28:46.323138Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-12-05T18:28:46.328311Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2021-12-05T18:28:47.333722Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2021-12-05T18:28:48.339275Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 ```
````

I've uninstalled MySQL using [these steps](https://gist.github.com/vitorbritto/0555879fe4414d18569d), and before reinstalling I do `brew remove mysql`, which results in `Error: No such keg: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql`. So I am fairly sure MySQL is no longer installed.

So is there a way to reset the root password (or failing that, reinstall MySQL)?

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue. Something during the upgrade corrupted the ibdata1 file and it failed to start as a result. Best solution I came up with was to uninstall MySQL

```
brew uninstall mysql
```

Then delete the data directory:

```
rm -rf /usr/local/var/mysql
```

and the custom conf

```
 rm /usr/local/etc/my.cnf
```

And then reinstall MySQL

```
brew install mysql
```